# Why Django inline_formset is not displayed in CreateView?

Tags: python, django, inline-formset, create-view

I have two models: TourLead and Languages. TourLead has a ForeignKey to Language. I need a CreateView to create TourLead instances and Language(using inline_formset). Created inline formset doesn't appear on a page. I declare it in template as {{lang_formset}}.

forms.py

```
class LeadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...

LanguageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    models.Language,
    models.TourLead,
    extra=1,
    exclude=[]
)
```

views.py

```
class LeadCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'leads/create-lead.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('leads-list')
    form_class = forms.LeadForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(LeadCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context_data['lang_formset'] = forms.LanguageFormSet()

        return context_data
```

models.py

```
class Language(models.Model):
    language = models.CharField(max_length=80,
                                verbose_name='Language')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.language


class TourLead(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80,
                            verbose_name='Name')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                              verbose_name='Gender')
    language = models.ForeignKey('Language')
    card_number = models.CharField(max_length=15,
                                   verbose_name='Card Number',
                                   blank=True,
                                   null=True)
    expire_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Expire Date',
                                   blank=True,
                                   null=True)
    professional = models.CharField(max_length=1,
                                    verbose_name='Professional')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```